# Where can I find OpenSSL 1.0.0 for Windows?

Tags: openssl

I have been searching the web, and can't seem to find a downloadable package of OpenSSL v1.0.0 for Windows. Does anyone know where I can find this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Judging by the [**Win32 OpenSSL**](http://www.slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html) page, it seems only 0.9.8 is currently available.

Although the author states:

> About OpenSSL 1.0.0: Today (April 23,
>   2010), I *FINALLY* received the new
>   laptop I've been waiting forever for
>   and now have a Windows 7 x64 build on
>   it. I've been planning to do the 1.0.0
>   release once I got this hardware
>   (partly because of the problems above)
>   so I can finally get started on the
>   new build.

so expect to see it soon! :)

Comment: you can also just built it yourself, its not that complicated (i have build 'our's on 1st april, there was a reaaaly ugly 'bug' in the 098er  version regarding random numbers on windows7)